# Why does open fail with LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610

Tags: command-line, dmg

Why am I getting `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610` when I try to `open` a `.dmg` on the command line?

```
user@host Downloads % open buskill-mac-x86_64.dmg
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610 for the file /Users/user/Downloads/buskill-mac-x86_64.dmg.
user@host Downloads %
```

I'm downloaded a `.dmg` file with `wget`, and now I want to `open` it. But when I do, I get the above error.

What does this `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610` error mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the official Apple API reference documentation for [`LSOpenURLsWithRole()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1448184-lsopenurlswithrole/)

Unfortunately, MacOS reference documenation is terrible and it doesn't say what erorr "-610" is.

Rather, like most thing with Apple, you can try to reverse-engineer it by grepping through C header files:

```
user@host ~ % cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs 
user@host SDKs % 

user@host SDKs % grep -ir '\-610' * 
...
noUserInteractionAllowed      = -610  /* no user interaction allowed */
...
user@host SDKs %
```

So in this case it appears that `-610` translates to `noUserInteractionAllowed`. And a quick google leads back to the [official Apple reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/nouserinteractionallowed), which is completely useless:

In my case, I found that the issue was that I wasn't logged-into the GUI.

My machine is headless, and I was only logged-in to the CLI via `ssh`. As soon as I logged-into the GUI and re-ran the command, the error went away.

Comment: It's usually a permissions error; no permission to execute. It could mean the file was quarantined. https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=LSOpenURLsWithRole

Comment: The issue goes away as soon as I log into the GUI. This one `-610` is not a permissions error, which is why I posted this Q&A